# Iphone: Get current view dimensions or screen dimensions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, screen, dimensions

Hello i want to get the width and height of my main view. I want the correct value in landscape or portrait mode. I've tried the following:

```
  NSLog(@"aaa %f", [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width);
  NSLog(@"zzz %f", self.view.frame.size.width);
```

These give 300 in landscape and 320 in portrait mode, yes it is larger in portrait mode. So.. my view takes up the whole screen (- status bar) so I expect 480 in landscape mode and 320 in portrait mode. What happened to the rest of the pixels. Do I have to hardcode these values? Thanks.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Do either of the following lines work for you?

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
```

I suppose you can subtract the height of the status bar? Maybe i'm not understanding your question

Comment: This works it returns the same width and height for both orientations but at least it works. And yes I need to substract the status bar.

Comment: @Omar you need an extra `[` before the UIScreen.

Comment: From iOS8 [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds
is interface-oriented (look at session "View Controller Advancements in iOS 8" of WWDC 2014), this means that in landscape mode on iOS8 height and width are reversed.

Comment: @Andr3a88,  Thanks for that additional info. This means that the original answer is even more satisfactory than it was before.

Answer (score 10):

Try this :

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
NSLog(@"%f",window.frame.size.width);
```

Answer (score 6):

Useful macros that will give you the correct size based on the device orientation:

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
```